# Changing font size of a label

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a label expression:`="Call Performance" & vbcrlf & Join(Parameters!client.Value,", ").  I added a carriage return after the constant text "Call Performance" so that I will automatically go at the bottom. How do I change the font size of the Parameters!Client.value? For example, "Client Performance" font size='18pts', "Company Name" font size='12 pts'.  Can the font size be configured within the SSRS expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **HTML** to format your text boxes with mixed formatting.

Instead of using **VBCRLF**, you'd need to use `< br>` for you line feed and use **SPAN** tags to format your selected text to another font/size/weight:

```
="Turnaround Days (Avg)<br>" & "<span style='font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold'>" 
& FORMATNUMBER(MAX(IIF(Fields!INDICATOR.Value = "AVG_DAYS", Fields!GRIEVANCES.Value, NOTHING), "INDICATORS"), 1) 
 & "</span>"
```

The text outside of the **SPAN** will use the font specs from the text box properties as usual.

To use **HTML** formatting in a text box, highlight your expression and right click and click on **Placeholder Properties** and select **HMTL**.

[image]

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

For more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207057(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you. Now I know I can use HTML tag in SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the expression with `=vbcrlf & Join(Parameters!client.Value,", ")` and type your constant before. Select the part of the string and change font size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

="Turnaround Days (Avg)
" & "" 
& FORMATNUMBER(MAX(IIF(Fields!INDICATOR.Value = "AVG_DAYS", Fields!GRIEVANCES.Value, NOTHING), "INDICATORS"), 1) 
 & ""